# Extending a class that doesn't seemed to be designed for it

Tags: c++, inheritance, private

I'm working with the UTF-8cpp library and i would like to create my own iterator class for the UTF-8 string class i'm writing.

My problem is that i need to have access to one of the members of the iterator class i'm extending, but i can access it neither directly because it is private, nor indirectly because there is no accessor for it.

I also don't want to modify the library. IMO that library should remain immutable, else it seems dirty.

What are the possibilities i have, except storing a copy of that member in my subclass, and except rewriting the same class with that member as protected ?

Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion, "open source" and "immutable" are contradictory ideas.

Comment: This question might be clearer if it were less abstract and contained more code.

Comment: Encapsulation. If a class is not designed to be extended, don't extend it. Use it as a service.

Comment: this is EXTREMLY not recomended and very CRAZY thing to do, but you can `#define private public` in some header file, than include the class interface, inherite publicly from it than `#undef private`. this is a voodoo magic and you should reconsider not using it at all.

Comment: What do you mean by use it as a service ?